# How to get reference to component in structural directive

Tags: angular

I want to make a structural directive that is specific to a component, and I also need a reference to that component. I'v tried like so:

```
<mat-progress-spinner *progress></mat-progress-spinner>
```

then:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[progress]' })
export class ProgressDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(
    private componentRef: ComponentRef<MatProgressSpinner>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) { }

}
```

but I get:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentRef!

I also tried:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[progress]' })
export class ProgressDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(MatProgressSpinner)
  public spinner: MatProgressSpinner;

  constructor(
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
  }

}
```

but spinner is undefined, even in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: why do you want it to be structural? what's the use case

Comment: I want a directive I can add to a mat-progress-spinner or mat-progress-bar that allows a service or something to effectively *ngIf  it and set the value (progress percentage)

Answer (score -1):

You should be directly able to use `<mat-progress-spinner>` in `*ngIf` condition. Make sure in your Component/Directive, you are setting the `mode(optional)`, `value` and `color` on the progress-spinner.

Comment: I know but I want to encapsulate this functionality in a directive